# JKS with multiple keys (different passwords)

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keystore, jks

I have a JKS with 2 keys generated using the keytool. The 2 keys have different passwords and the JKS password is again different from these 2 passwords.

If there is only one key in the key store, it works as expected. But adding another with a different password results in an `UnrecoverableKeyException`. If the two keys have the same password, it still works fine.

Looking at some of the questions related to this: [Java keystore with multiple keys and different passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709433/java-keystore-with-multiple-keys-and-different-passwords), [Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967650/caused-by-java-security-unrecoverablekeyexception-cannot-recover-key?noredirect=1&lq=1) it seems the solution is to use the same password. But that means there's no point in being able to set different passwords to different keys; we can just set a password to the whole key store and leave it at that.

Looking at [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Prepare_the_Certificate_Keystore), it also seems to follow this approach of using the same password for both the store and the key.

Is this a restriction imposed by the JDK? Isn't there a way to make having different passwords for different keys work?

Comment: JDK allows differering passwords; that's why (and how) keytool could create this. _Tomcat below 8.5_ does not. The way to use different passwords is to use some webservers other than Tomcat, or to use Tomcat 8.5 up configured with multiple (explicit) `SSLHost` and `Certificate` items. Note Tomcat 6 officially died over a year ago.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't even realize I was looking at an older version. That link was in a discussion in one of those questions I mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a restriction by the JDK, and the [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#KeyManagerFactory) answers your question :

> For many factories, such as the default SunX509 KeyManagerFactory from
>   the SunJSSE provider, the KeyStore and password are the only
>   information required to initialize the KeyManagerFactory and thus the
>   first init method is the appropriate one to call. The
>   KeyManagerFactory will query the KeyStore for information about which
>   private key and matching public key certificates should be used for
>   authenticating to a remote socket peer. The password parameter
>   specifies the password that will be used with the methods for
>   accessing keys from the KeyStore. All keys in the KeyStore must be
>   protected by the same password.
>
> Sometimes initialization parameters other than a KeyStore and password
>   are needed by a provider. Users of that provider are expected to pass
>   an implementation of the appropriate ManagerFactoryParameters as
>   defined by the provider. The provider can then call the specified
>   methods in the ManagerFactoryParameters implementation to obtain the
>   needed information.

You now know what to do, implement your own ManagerFactoryParameters. But if you have to also change the Tomcat's code, it's another thing.